# Webservice callout 403

Tags: apex, callout

I am trying to call a webservice from Salesforce but getting a `403 Forbidden` response. I have already added the endpoint URL in `Remote Site Settings`. My code is:

```
public with sharing class CallUpdatePersonAttributes_pt {


    @future (callout=true)
    public static void updateCDBPerson(){
         HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port/PersonDS/ProxyService/PersonDS');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
            //req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/CreateCustomerProfile');//

            //send the request
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            string b =   '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'+
                      '<soap:Body>'+
                    '<ns1:UpdatePersonAttributesRequest xmlns:ns1="urn:engineersaustralia:cdm:generic:common:service:v1">'+
                    '<ns1:PersonID>2713020</ns1:PersonID>'+
            '<ns1:Sex>M</ns1:Sex>'+
            '<ns1:UpdatedBy>1111</ns1:UpdatedBy>'+
        '</ns1:UpdatePersonAttributesRequest>'+
    '</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
        req.setBody(b);
        try{
            res = http.send(req);
             System.debug(res.toString());
          System.debug('STATUS:'+res.getStatus());
          System.debug('STATUS_CODE:'+res.getStatusCode());
        }
        catch(System.CalloutException e){}

    }

}
```

The trigger code is:

```
trigger TestDBAdapTrigger on Contact (after update) {

    for(Contact ct:Trigger.new){
        CallUpdatePersonAttributes_pt.updateCDBPerson();
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a salesforce authentication method, when you should be using an authentication method specific to the service you are trying to access.  `req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());`

Comment: 403 means user is not authorized. You have to provide security credential to access the Web Service. Try to call the Web Service from post man by providing security details and debug there, once you successfully connected implement it in Salesforce.